# Unknown Apple app qlmanage shows up as running in Dock

Tags: macos

Since a few days, an app called qlmanage seems to show up on my Dock as a running app constantly. Have tried restarting, but it shows up again.

The app has no window, and clicking on its icon on the dock seems to does nothing.

Trying to quit the app has no effect either.

It seems to be part of OS X (
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/qlmanage.1.html)

Can someone throw some light on what's happening? I checked `Login Items` but it isn't listed there.

Edit:
Actually it was qLmanage (with lowercase 'l') not qImanage as I'd thought. With this "knowledge" :D , I was able to find the solution to my problem.

Comment: are you connecting to a Server ? Quick Look Server debug and management tool

Comment: Nope. What kind of server? But nope, not connecting to any server (unless some app's doing it without my knowledge).